# OpenGL ES 2.0 - Array of vec2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I have a `GLSL shader` program running my iPhone app (it's a very very simple shader). I am trying to declare an array of `vec2` but I'm having a lot of trouble. My shader is wrapped in a thrid party library, so unfortunately I can't get any real information about the actual error in syntax is.

My code (not working) to declare an array of vec2 is:

```
highp vec2 steps[5] = vec2[](
                            vec2(   0.0015625,  0.00208333333333),
                            vec2(    0.003125,  0.00416666666667),
                            vec2(     0.00625,  0.00833333333333),
                            vec2(      0.0125,  0.0166666666667),
                            vec2(       0.025,  0.0333333333333)
                            );
```

**Does anyone have any idea how to create an array of `vec2` datatypes in OpenGLES 2.0?**

Comment: I can't test this right now, but wrap the array in `{};` instead of `vec2[]();`

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
highp vec2 steps[5] = {
                            vec2(   0.0015625,  0.00208333333333),
                            vec2(    0.003125,  0.00416666666667),
                            vec2(     0.00625,  0.00833333333333),
                            vec2(      0.0125,  0.0166666666667),
                            vec2(       0.025,  0.0333333333333)
                            };
```

Comment: This isn't valid ES2 Shading Language syntax. Does it really compile for you? Doesn't for me.

Comment: DOsn't compile for me either. How comes this is voted up?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's possible to create, but I am not sure it's possible to initialize it at declaration time. According to the OpenGL ES specification, http://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf

> There is no mechanism for initializing arrays at declaration time from
>   within a shader.